# iOS Arabic localization issue in iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, localization, ios10

I have developed the application where I need to provide the support for two language English and Arabic. In application there is a setting screen where user can change the language from english to arabic and vice versa.

For more information please find the below screenshot for the same.

[image]

And the code which perform the `localization` where I had refreshed the `storyboard` to update UI.

```
- (void)updateLanguage {

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNavigationController"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:vc];
}
```

As from `iOS 8` to `iOS 9`, it works fine and update the UI but in `iOS 10` it does not update the UI. For more information please review the below screenshot.

[image]

How I can achieve for update the UI in `iOS 10`?

Below is the proper UI which need to be updated in `iOS 10`.

[image]

> Note : When the application came from background to foreground then it
>   is working fine.

Comment: what prob you are facing and which part ?

Comment: Actually the UI is not updated in iOS 10 which you are probably visible in last screenshot.

Comment: HK, is that above navigation code not working or your `uilables` not updating language ?

Comment: uilables is updating according to language changes but as you see in the last screenshot the layout is not updated.

Comment: cant get your prob, which layout not updating ?

Comment: In Arabic mode the layout is start from Right to Left and in English mode the layout is Left to Right, so in arabic mode the layout is not update from LTR to RTL and vice versa.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125496/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-ramkrishna-sharma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way how to update the layout based on language selection using `UISemanticContentAttribute`.

**Objective C**

```
if(IS_OS_10_OR_LATER) {

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Ln"] isEqualToString:@"Ar"])
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
    else
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
}
```

As I had stored the current language selection in `NSUserDefaults` and accordingly update the layout.

**SWIFT 3.0**

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

Comment: Is it possible for datepicker date & time?

Comment: I did not get you properly, please elaborate.

Comment: I have datepicker.When I change to Arabic language,date & time of date picker must change from right to left inside the datepicker.I use your above code but date & time is not changing from right to left inside the datepicker.

Comment: If it is "Today 4:30 PM" inside the datepicker for English Language, it must be "PM 4:30 Today" in the datepicker for Arabic Language.

Comment: For that I need to check it, as I did not have the datepicker in my application.

Comment: I tried lot of ways but nothing helped me to solve this.

Comment: The Right to Left works only when second time run the app

Comment: Try with sample and tell me please.

Comment: sure I will do.